# Pass typedef to a function

Tags: esp32

I'm working with a ESP32S3 that will manage 2 I2S ports, so for the cleanness of my code and also because i'll work multiple I2S installations - deinstallations, i want to move all the functions to and ".cpp .h" file.

something like this

1. I2S_functions.h

   ```
   #ifndef I2S_FUNCTIONS_H
   #define I2S_FUNCTIONS_H
   #include <Arduino.h>
   #include <driver/i2s.h>

   void i2s_install(i2s_port_t I2S_PORT, i2s_mode_t I2S_MODE, float I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
   i2s_bits_per_sample_t I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,i2s_channel_fmt_t I2S_CHANNEL,i2s_comm_format_t I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,int buf_count, int buf_len, bool apll);

   #endif
   ```
2. I2S_functions.cpp

```
#include "I2S_functions.h"

void i2s_install(i2s_port_t I2S_PORT, i2s_mode_t I2S_MODE, float I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
i2s_bits_per_sample_t I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,i2s_channel_fmt_t I2S_CHANNEL,i2s_comm_format_t I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,
int buf_count, int buf_len, bool apll)
{
  const i2s_config_t i2s_config = 
  {
    
    .mode = I2S_MODE,
    //.mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE),
    .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
    
    .bits_per_sample = I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,
    .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL,
    .communication_format = i2s_comm_format_t(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S),
    
    .intr_alloc_flags = 0, // default interrupt priority
    .dma_buf_count = buf_count,//cambiado de 8 a 64
    .dma_buf_len = buf_len,
    .use_apll = apll
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_PORT, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
}
```

3. main.ino

```
#include "I2S_functions.h"

// I2S config //////
#include <driver/i2s.h>

#define I2S_PORT I2S_NUM_0
//#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE  (44100) 
float I2S_SAMPLE_RATE=44100;
int I2S_SAMPLE_BITS=32;
//#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS  (32)
#define bufferLen 1024
#define I2S_READ_LEN (16*1024)


void setup ()
{
  i2s_install(I2S_PORT,I2S_MODE_MASTER|I2S_MODE_RX,I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, 
I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_32BIT,I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,8,bufferLen,false);

}
```

But when i compile this, i got errors passing the second argument which is "I2S_MODE_MASTER|I2S_MODE_RX,I2S_SAMPLE_RATE"

a copy from the error:

```
C:\Users\.ino: In function 'void setup()':
test_10seg_V2:52:39: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'i2s_mode_t' [-fpermissive]
   i2s_install(I2S_PORT,I2S_MODE_MASTER|I2S_MODE_RX,I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\.ino:2:
C:\Users\I2S_functions.h:6:50: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void i2s_install(i2s_port_t, i2s_mode_t, float, i2s_bits_per_sample_t, i2s_channel_fmt_t, i2s_comm_format_t, int, int, bool)'
 void i2s_install(i2s_port_t I2S_PORT, i2s_mode_t I2S_MODE, float I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,

exit status 1
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'i2s_mode_t' [-fpermissive]
```

**Essentially i have 2 questions**. While i looked in the github from the esp32 i found off that there is some typedef of the I2S config (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/sdk/esp32/include/hal/include/hal/i2s_types.h). I've never worked with this type of structs before so i am guessing how should i use it and specially how should i pass this type of variables to a function.

```
typedef enum {
    I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_8BIT    = 8,            /*!< data bit-width: 8 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT   = 16,           /*!< data bit-width: 16 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_24BIT   = 24,           /*!< data bit-width: 24 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_32BIT   = 32,           /*!< data bit-width: 32 */
} i2s_bits_per_sample_t;

/**
 * @brief I2S bit width per chan.
 *
 */
typedef enum {
    I2S_BITS_PER_CHAN_DEFAULT        = (0),      /*!< channel bit-width equals to data bit-width */
    I2S_BITS_PER_CHAN_8BIT           = (8),      /*!< channel bit-width: 8 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_CHAN_16BIT          = (16),     /*!< channel bit-width: 16 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_CHAN_24BIT          = (24),     /*!< channel bit-width: 24 */
    I2S_BITS_PER_CHAN_32BIT          = (32),     /*!< channel bit-width: 32 */
} i2s_bits_per_chan_t;
```

my questions are

**1.-** I would like to understand how this structs works. I want to clean my code the most that i could, and that mean passing a lot of functions out of the main file. So any resource is well welcome to improve my coding skill.

**2.-** Why the code fails passing this 2 variables "I2S_MODE_MASTER|I2S_MODE_RX" ?. Is there any special way of passing this variables when are 2 options at once?.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: this is more a general C++ programming question, than it is an Arduino question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type

Answer (score 2):

Answer to Question 1: The `typedef` code you posted is `enum` and not `struct`. Look up C++ Enumeration and you will find lots of good tutorials. Here is [one video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWlbuyQ2eig).

Answer to Question 2:  You need to typecast the argument for your function to accept it as `i2s_mode_t`.

```
i2s_install(I2S_PORT, (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER|I2S_MODE_RX), ... ... ...);
```

Comment: i2s_mode_t it is an example of a very bad API design. it should never be an enum.